# Can regex be used for cropping?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Let's say I have these three lines:

```
the quick brown fox
the brown fox
the quick brown quick fox
```

Can regex be used to crop out everything in each line except for the word `quick`?

The end result would look like this:

```
quick

quickquick
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that it's in the context of a search-and-replace (in Sublime Text 2, more specifically).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specifics depend on the language you are using, but here are a few common approaches for doing this with regex (code samples in Python):

- Find all matches of your target string, and then combine each match into a single string:

  ```
  >>> import re
  >>> s = 'the quick brown quick fox'
  >>> ''.join(re.findall('quick', s))
  'quickquick'
  ```
- Construct a regex to match everything **except** your target string, and then replace each match with an empty string (*this is usually much more difficult than the other alternatives listed)*:

  ```
  >>> re.sub('(?!quick|(?<=q)uick|(?<=qu)ick|(?<=qui)ck|(?<=quic)k).', '', s)
  'quickquick'
  ```
- Use capturing groups to match everything up until an occurrence of a target string, and then replace with just the target string:

  ```
  >>> re.sub('.*?(quick|$)', r'\1', s)
  'quickquick'
  ```

If your string has multiple lines as in your example, you can either split the strings on line breaks first or adapt the solutions to keep line breaks, for example:

```
>>> s = '''the quick brown fox
... the brown fox
... the quick brown quick fox'''
>>> print ''.join(re.findall('quick|[\r\n]', s))
quick

quickquick
>>> print re.sub('.*?(quick|$)', r'\1', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
quick

quickquick
```

Comment: > Construct a regex to match everything except your target string, and then replace each match with an empty string.
Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Pogo Trying to come up with one now, but it will have to be a fairly complex regex.

Comment: @Pogo Edited my answer with an example for that second bullet, but it is ugly.

Comment: Actually no, it's not more complex, as you yourself demonstrated.  Your third (and by far your best) solution seems to works perfectly on the multiline sample.

Comment: Oh, and number three is definitely the winner.

Answer (score 1):

Regex alone isn't used to manipulate strings.  It only does pattern matching.  Depending on the tool you are using to implement it, you can usually do string replacement with regex matches.  For example, from a Bash terminal, you could us Sed, or from PHP you can use preg_replace().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, regular expressions are capable of that search by implementing `lookahead` and `lookbehind`[constructions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

For example, here is the Python program using positive lookahead expression that does what you need:

```
import re

s = '''the quick brown fox
the brown fox
the quick brown quick fox'''

rx = re.compile('(?!quick).*')
print rx.findall(s)
```

Output:

```
['the quick brown fox', '', 'the brown fox', '', 'the quick brown quick fox', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **sed** for this:

```
sed -r 's/(quick|)./\1/g' file.txt
```